# how to loop through objects and change the property keys in a data set

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, dataformat

I have a set of data that needs to be reformatted according to a specific format that i desire.
Below is the format of data that I'm receiving.

```
      const recieved = [
    {
      "name": "1PM Industries Inc ",
      "series": [
        {
          "value": 0.0001,
          "name": "2019-08-30"
        },
        {
          "value": 0,
          "name": "2019-08-28"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

What i need to do is iterate through all object property keys `"name"`, `"series"`, `"value"` and change them to `"id"`, `"data"` , `"x"` and `"y"` respectively.

Below is the format of data that i want the above data set to be changed.
I need the `"name"` to be replaced with `"x"` and `"value"` should be replaced with `"y"`

```
  const columns = [
    {
      "id": "japan",
      "data": [
        {
          "x": "plane",
          "y": 45
        },
        {
          "x": "helicopter",
          "y": 253
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

I found out that we can access property keys of objects by `Object.keys`

```
  function formatData(columns) {
    columns.map(col => {

    })
  }
```

I find myself in really hard situations when it comes to formatting of data. Hope someone could help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
received.map(r => ({
  id: r.name,
  data: r.series.map(s => ({
    x: s.name,
    y: s.value
  }))
}));
```

Map over each received object, return a new object. `id` of the new object is `name` of the received object. `data` of new object is a map of `series` of old objects converting `name` to `x` and `value` to `y`.

Answer (score 1):

You could rename the properties ([Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names)) and generate new objects.

```js
const
    recieved = [{ name: "1PM Industries Inc ", series: [{ value: 0.0001, name: "2019-08-30" }, { value: 0, name: "2019-08-28" }] }],
    result = recieved.map(({ name: id, series }) => ({ 
        id, 
        data: series.map(({ value: x, name: y }) => ({ x, y }))
    }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method for this.

```
const recieved = [
            {
              "name": "1PM Industries Inc ",
              "series": [
                {
                  "value": 0.0001,
                  "name": "2019-08-30"
                },
                {
                  "value": 0,
                  "name": "2019-08-28"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
    let output = recieved.map(o=>{
            let data = o.series.map((i)=>{ return {x: i.value, y: i.name}});
            return {id: o.name, data}
        });

    console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use for..in loop in conjunction with hasOwnProperty() method

use recursion to have a better script